# Service - Controller connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry, I'm new to webDev. How I can get data from factory to mainCtrl.

Code:

```
shopApp.controller("mainCtrl",function($scope,newItemsFactory){
    $scope.newItems=newItemsFactory.getNewItems();
    console.log($scope.newItems);  //NOT WORK
});

shopApp.factory('newItemsFactory',function($http){
    return{
        getNewItems:function(){
            $http({method: 'GET', url: '../php/newItems.php'}).
                then (function success(response) {
                       return response.data;
                    }, function error(response) {
                        console.log("Error!");
                    }
                );
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you)

Comment: Return promise from factory method, `return $http....` and in controller use `.then()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should return `Promise` from `newItemsFactory.getNewItems()`:

```
getNewItems:function(){
    return $http({method: 'GET', url: '../php/newItems.php'});
}
```

use `Promise.then` to deal with the result and `Promise.catch` to deal with the error in your controller:

```
$scope.newItems=newItemsFactory.getNewItems().then(function(response) {
    $scope.newItems = response.data;
}.catch(function error(response) {
    console.log("Error!");
};
```

Comment: Thank, you are awesome.